# Risk Management methods for Stock portfolio with ~30 stocks

Tags: equities, risk, risk-management, value-at-risk

What is ideal Risk Management method/methods s for stock portfolios with 25-30 stocks and around 50.000 USD invested in those stocks. Every stock bought will be kept in the portfolio for 1 to 12 months. (no day-trading)

I have been working in a bank where we use Value-at-Risk. My intuition tells me that VaR will be preferable for bigger portfolios and it might not be ideal in my case.

So; **what kind of Risk Management tools/methods will you recommend?**

I have not yet decided how "Risky" I am and how I will let Risk Manegenemt influence my strategy. At first I just want to setup a Risk Management system for having an overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a "long only" portfolio and the stocks are fairly diversified sector-wise:

A portfolio of 25-30 more or less equally weighted stocks most likely will have a strong-ish positive correlation with a broad indexes such as S&P500. If this is the case, then you can define limits (volatility based stop-loss, VaR/CVaR, MaxDD) depending on your risk tolerance. Furthermore, just recently [Asness of AQR proposed an interesting way of modelling risk using VIX](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Perspectives/Wild-But-Not-Crazy). That model could be improved as he kept naming it "a toy".

If the idea is to have a low correlation/beta with the market, then you have to:

- identify your benchmark;
- analyze individual stock volatilities and correlations/covariances;
- analyze total portfolio volatility and beta against the benchmark;
- look at risk/volatility contribution (in terms of either standard deviation or VaR/CVaR) of each stock;
- define limits (volatility based stop-loss, VaR/CVaR, MaxDD -- both individual and aggregate) based on your risk tolerance;

This might be far from ideal for you, but should at least give some information on risks of your investments/portfolio.